# Backbone.io, Backbone, and require.js

Tags: backbone.js, socket.io, requirejs

How can I load Backbone.io, Backbone, and socket.io with Require.js's shim config?

It seems like everything else is loading just fine, just that when I attempt to run Backbone.io.connect() I get "Backbone is not defined". Backbone.io is served the same way socket.io is from the /socket.io directory that the socket.io server creates.

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'javascripts/lib',
  paths: {
    jquery: 'jquery.min',
    bootstrap: 'bootstrap.min'
  },
  shim : {
    'underscore': {
      exports: '_'
    },
    'backbone': {
      deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    'bootstrap': {
      deps: ["jquery"]
    }
  }
})

requirejs(['jquery',
           'underscore',
           'backbone',
           'bootstrap',
           '../socket.io/socket.io.js',
           '../socket.io/backbone.io.js'
           ], function($, 
                       _,
                       Backbone,
                       bootstrap){

    Backbone.io.connect();
}
```

---

small update:

It seems like Backbone is defined just fine in the main requirejs function, it's just that backbone.io needs Backbone to be defined before it's initialized. How can I initialize the Backbone object and THEN the backbone.io library so it can do it's thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try including backbone in your path

```
paths: {
    jquery: 'jquery.min',
    bootstrap: 'bootstrap.min',
    underscore: '<name of underscore file>',
    backbone: '<name of backbone file>'
},
```

I think that should do it. Remember not to include the .js in the file name.
Also, if backbone.io depends on backbone you may need to add the dependencies under shim.

```
shim : {
    'underscore': {
      exports: '_'
    },
    'backbone': {
      deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    'bootstrap': {
      deps: ["jquery"]
    },
    'backbone.io': {
      deps: ["backbone"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help. The backbone and underscore libraries aren't minified while I'm developing, so they're just backbone.js, and underscore.js.

Comment: If it isn't minified, in path just put backbone: 'name of backbone file without .js', and yes I believe Paul is correct, you'll need to put underscore : 'name of underscore file without .js' in the path as well. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how it ended up working for me:

Thanks landland, your answer helped the most.

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl: 'javascripts/lib',
  paths: {
    jquery: 'jquery.min',
    bootstrap: 'bootstrap.min',
    backbone: 'backbone',
    underscore: 'underscore',
    socketio: '../../socket.io/socket.io',
    backboneio: '../../socket.io/backbone.io'
  },
  shim : {
    'underscore': {
      exports: '_'
    },
    'backbone': {
      deps: ["underscore", "jquery"],
      exports: 'Backbone'
    },
    'bootstrap': {
      deps: ["jquery"],
      exports: 'bootstrap'
    },
    'backboneio': {
      deps: ["backbone", "socketio"]
    }
  }
})

requirejs(['jquery',
           'underscore',
           'backbone',
           'bootstrap',
           'socketio',
           'backboneio'
           ], function($, 
                       _,
                       Backbone,
                       bootstrap,
                       titlealert,
                       waitForImages){
}
```